# Unable to deploy fine-tuned curie model in Azure OpenAI

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have a sucessful fine-tuned curie model job and model id. But I can't deploy it either from cli, or portal. In the portal I get this error:

> Failed to create 1 out of 1 model deployments
> ips_model_curie: The model 'Format: OpenAI, Name: curie.ft-xxx-ips_model, Version: 1' of account deployment is not supported.

Can anyone advise what is not supported and how I might overcome this?

I have tried from:

- Python Code
- CLI
- Portal
- OpenAI portal

I am able to deploy the base models, but not fine tuned models.

Answer (score 1):

If I do the **fine tuning** with the UI ("create a customized model") and the exact same training files, the fine tune model will deploy. This is probably a bug in the python examples or microsoft openai wrapping of the openai stuff. If I find out I will post here, but for now if you run into this problem, do the fine tuning via the UI.

Comment: It works now, it was a bug in the API that was fixed.